# Как разделить строку методом re.split по шаблону сепаратора re. выражения?

Tags: python, split, re

```py
import re

string = 'м/к 6м 07.11.17 3м 30.05.18 м/к 6м 28.04.21/конс.п/тер 13.07.21 м/к 6мес 08.11.21 м/к 6мес (1ф) 13.05.22'

re.split(r"(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2,4}[;\s]?)", string)
```

У меня получается так:

```py
['м/к 6м 07', '11.17 3', 'м 30', '05.18 ', 'м/к 6м 28', '04.21/', 'конс.п/тер 13', '07.21 ', 'м/к 6мес 08', '11.21 ', 'м/к 6мес (1ф) 13.05.22']
```

Мне необходимо получить список такого содержания

```py
['м/к 6м 07.11.17', '3м 30.05.18', 'м/к 6м 28.04.21', 'конс.п/тер 13.07.21', 'м/к 6мес 08.11.21', 'м/к 6мес (1ф) 13.05.22']
```

Строка должна быть разделена по дате, дата конец строки. Помогите решить эту задачу :)

Comment: Символ '.' в re - специальный. Поэтому, если он используется в литеральном смысле, то его надо маскировать. Вот так: r"\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2,4}". Но тогда вся та часть строки, которая совпала с этим re воспримется как разделитель и при разбиении строки исчезнет и получится только:  ['м/к 6м ', ' 3м ', ' м/к 6м ', '/конс.п/тер ', ' м/к 6мес ', ' м/к 6мес (1ф) ', '']

Comment: можно вот так `re.split(r"(?<=\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})", string)` но "заглядываание назад" требует фиксированную длину. так что, если бывают годы и в 3 и в 4 цифры не получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да в принципе даже с не экранированной точкой будет работать, если сделать наоборот поиск, а не разбиение, но добавить не-жадный шаблон для произвольной строки спереди и "хвост" убрать из скобок, чтобы не захватывался:

```
import re

string = 'м/к 6м 07.11.17 3м 30.05.18 м/к 6м 28.04.21/конс.п/тер 13.07.21 м/к 6мес 08.11.21 м/к 6мес (1ф) 13.05.22'

re.findall(r"(.*?\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2,4})[;\s]?", string)
```

На выходе:

```
['м/к 6м 07.11.17 ',
 '3м 30.05.18',
 'м/к 6м 28.04.21',
 '/конс.п/тер 13.07.21 ',
 'м/к 6мес 08.11.21',
 'м/к 6мес (1ф) 13.05.22']
```

Для более произвольного количества цифр в числах можно так, но точку тогда лучше всё-таки экранировать:

```
re.findall(r"(.*?\d+\.\d+\.\d+)[;\s]?", string)
```

Comment: Да спасибо, это очень простое и компактное решения, а то я две функции написал что бы добиться такого же эффекта. Вы мне очень помогли! Хотел выложить свое решение этой задачи, но на фоне вашего решения, мое очень громоздкое - воспользуюсь вашим. Спасибо!